# Right Click in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, right-click, contextmenu

I have been trying to add context based right click in windows explorer for a file of extension L5X.  I have tried HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\l5xfile\Shell\convert\command and set the (Default) key value to the program I want to have open the file.  (I want it to say "Convert" on the context menu)  My first issue seems to be that in .NET (even when running elevated) I cannot change the Default key's value.  My other issue is changing that Default key value doesn't do anything to the context menu.  I would really prefer a no reboot required solution.

Also, I really need this to work on WinXP all the way up to Win7 (including Server 2003, 2008 and 2008R2).  If I need to detect OS and do things differently for different OSes, I will but I'm really stuck here.

PS, I tried the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664046/create-custom-right-click-context-menu-item-with-c-for-all-desktop-shortcuts-wi) with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

You need administrator rights to write to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT is a merged view of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes and HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes. If you want to install it for just the current user, write to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes

---

\l5xfile\Shell\convert\command might not be the correct path, when windows looks for context menu entries for a filetype, it first looks in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.EXT`, then uses the default value it finds there: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\%defaultvaluefrom.EXT%\Shell\*`

XP added a new key [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776871(v=vs.85).aspx) designed for non-primary actions where you don't care about the ProgId/Class (The l5xfile part)

MSDN documents all these registry paths and settings, see: [File Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776870(v=vs.85).aspx) and [Verbs and File Associations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776883(v=vs.85).aspx)